# How to increment a hexadecimal loop in expect

Tags: expect

How can I make a loop that increment a hexadecimal variable in *expect* ?
I would like something like that.

```
while min < max do 
  print hexValue
  hexValue++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set min 0x0000;
set max 0xFFFF ;

while {$min < $max } {
    puts [format %04X $min]
    sleep 1;
    set min [expr $min+1];
}
```

Will output:

```
debian@debian:~/Desktop$ ./test.sh 
0000
0001
0002
0003
0004
0005
0006
0007
0008
0009
000A
000B
000C
000D
000E
000F
0010
```